# Do we use await on async functions which use await?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I have a Rest API endpoint `/foo/bar` and I am calling it from and async function `bar()` and I am calling that function from another function `foo ()` like so

```
async function bar () {
    let result;

    result = await $.ajax({}); /* pseudocode only */
    return result;
}

function foo () {
    let result;

    result = bar ();
    console.log ('This should display before the result, not after it');
    console.log (result);
    console.log ('This should display after the result, not before it');

foo();
```

I am getting inconsistent results and I want to know if it is because I need to instead make foo asynchronous like so

```
async function bar () {
    let result;

    result = await $.ajax({}); /* pseudocode only */
    return result;
}

async function foo () {
    let result;

    result = await bar ();
    console.log ('This should display before the result, not after it');
    console.log (result);
    console.log ('This should display after the result, not after it');

foo();
```

Basically my question is whether an await inside an async function renders that function synchronous (ie. it blocks the calling function until the await returns)?

Comment: yes you do - otherwise you will just get the Promise`

Comment: you can't block a function in javascript

Comment: Yes, `await` stops execution of the function (and only the function!) till the promise resolves. However that's what in fact makes async functions asynchronous, because you don't know when execution continues.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Async functions will return a Promise so, if you'd like to wait for the response of an async function, you will need the await.

Answer (score 0):

an `async` function by definition [returns a Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#return_value) so you deal with the result in the same way as any other Promise.

Which basically means you either do what's in your second snippet, with `async/await`:

```
async function foo () {
    let result;

    result = await bar ();
    console.log (result);
}
```

or alternatively you can use `.then`:

```
function foo() {
    bar().then(result => console.log(result));
}
```